# Adding multiprocessing to threading code in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, packet-capture

I am writing a Python 3 script to sniff and process wireless packets. Right now, I am able to use threading and run simultaneously a producer and a consumer.

The producer sniffs packet and puts each one in a queue, in real time, and the consumer gets packets from the queue.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from scapy.all import *

queue = Queue(10)

class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            print("Starting producer thread")
            sniff(iface="wlan2mon", store=0, prn=queue_packet)

def queue_packet(packet):
    queue.put(packet)

class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            p = queue.get()
            queue.task_done()
            print(p.summary())


ProducerThread().start()
ConsumerThread().start()
```

And I would like to be able to parallelize the consumer part having more consumers to be able to analyze huge traffic networks.

Is it a good idea to mix concurrency and parallelism? How can I do such a thing?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a typical multithreaded application: One producer and multiple consumers. It only really makes sense if the consumption takes longer than the production and you have the cores to parallelise the consumption. Just add more consumer threads.

Comment: @quamrana, first of all thank you for your answer. I am bit worried about the performance, I just test it with few packets and it works fine, but I have read some articles about GIL, so that's why I prefer to parallelize it instead of creating more threads. Also, I would like to do check to check the performance between threading producer and consumer and threading producer and parallelizing consumers.

Comment: I'm struggling to find good info on how you can multiprocess a task in a threaded application. Google matches are generally about the difference between the two, and not about using them together. Nice question. I suspect you may have to stress test it yourself.

Comment: Yes, in python the GIL will stomp all over `multithreading`, although it is still useful for I/O bound apps. However, `multiprocessing` uses processes to bypass the GIL and allows compute bound functions to use the hyperthreaded cores of your CPU to the full.